# Autorunning Query in mysql

Tags: mysql, automation, mysql-event

Is it possible to make a stored procedure that run every night 11 pm , check in table if any record is modified for last six month, If some record is modified for last six month I have to delete it from table. This has to run automatically without use of any external language.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `my_old_data_cleaner_event`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 23 DAY_HOUR
COMMENT 'Clean up Service Start at 11:00PM daily!'
DO DELETE FROM my_table WHERE created_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

OR for Stored Procedure.

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `my_old_data_cleaner_event`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 23 DAY_HOUR
DO CALL my_sp_cleanup_old_data();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .... can you please say that how we run this query without calling from any external language.

Comment: its my mistake if we create an event in MySQL it will run automatically rit. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve with mysql event scheduler--

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

detail blog: http://goo.gl/6Hzjvg

Answer (score 0):

Create an event like below

```
CREATE EVENT e_daily
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
 DO
   BEGIN
     DELETE FROM tableA WHERE DATE(`yourtimestamp`) <(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTHS);
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a script that processes your data in Python, Perl, PHP, etc.

After that, simply setup cron entry using `crontab -e` and add following line:

```
0 23 * * * /path/to/my/script.pl 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

If you don't specify `2>&1 >/dev/null`, you will get email with execution results.