# How to insert data into mysql automatically by certain datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.  The first is `inventory_control` and the second is `stock`.

- table `inventory_control` is recorded stock opname a warehouse and every receiving or dispatching event, data is always updated.
- table `stock` is related to accounting.

Every day at 00:00 o'clock, all data in the `inventory_control` table needs to be inserted into table `stock` automatically.

I have no idea about that. I have searched in google and I didn't find something useful. I learned about trigger and I didn't think trigger can help.

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE 'inventory_control' (
'warehouse', varchar(100) unsigned NOT NULL,
'idItem', int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
'Quantity' int(8) unsigned);


CREATE TABLE 'stock'(
'warehouse', varchar(100) unsigned NOT NULL,
'idItem', int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
'Quantity' int(8) unsigned,
'value', int(11) unsigned);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your cpanel you could use cron jobs by running php script file

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0613s35q6c

like this

php -f /home/your_username/public_html/script.php   and ajust the time there

Answer (score 0):

I'm borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13872758/1470257), and [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/64208), but you can create an event:

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `daily_event`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 00 DAY_HOUR
COMMENT 'Insert data from inventory_control to stock'
DO INSERT INTO inventory_control SELECT * FROM stock;
```

However, if you want to run this each night, you probably want to edit this since this query will append *all* of the `stock` table each night to the `inventory_control` table. This can lead to a lot of repetitive data. A better query (assuming you have a `timestamp` field or something similar for each record) would be:

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `daily_event`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2014-11-04 00:00:00'
COMMENT 'Insert data from inventory_control to stock'
DO INSERT INTO inventory_control SELECT * FROM stock 
WHERE 'timestamp' BETWEEN CURDATE() - 2 AND CURDATE() - 1;
```

This will run the query every night at midnight, and will only add records that were created in the last 24 hours.

EDIT: Events will not be scheduled unless the MySQL [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html) is configured

EDIT2: Be sure to check out the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) on Event Scheduling for the full list of what you can do!

Comment: @Diyah sure no problem! Be sure to accept the answer if this is what you're looking for ;)