# PHP Sleep Function 2 days time?

Tags: mysql, function, sleep

I'm trying to find a way to execute a function (send some emails), 2 days after a new table is inserted into the database. I would like to do this without cron if possible, so I was wondering if is too wrong to use the sleep function, with 2 days time? Or any other suggestion..

Comment: *"I would like to do this without cron if possible"* - Why?

Comment: Why not cron? Also, I'm curious: What needs to be done two days after a table insert?

Comment: If you even attempted this you'd have to set the PHP timeout limit stupidly high for it to keep running, which can lead to other issues.  Plus then if you get a lot of table creations, you'll have loads of processes stacked up doing nothing for a couple of days.

Comment: This is the first time I read something like this. The longest sleep I've seen a script doing was like a single minute. Two days!! Holy, one does not simply sleep two days. You can't do this. PHP will never wake up from that state.

Comment: `sleep()` for 2 days will lock a worker for nothing and will certainly timeout (and reinvent the CRON wheel). "No cron" because the hosting service don't provide these? Then change for a better one.

Comment: Use a free cron-http-ping service (Google for free cron).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SCHEDULE** to set schedule for database query.

Maybe this question is already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872598/autorunning-query-in-mysql)